# RIP Ursula Le Guin

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Ursula K. Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin), one of the greatest science fiction and fantasy writers of all time, [sadly passed away](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/23/obituaries/ursula-k-le-guin-acclaimed-for-her-fantasy-fiction-is-dead-at-88.html) yesterday at the age of 88. Her writing career spans six decades, from 1959 right up until 2017, and [her writings include](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin_bibliography) speculative fiction, realistic fiction, non-fiction, screenplays, librettos, essays, poetry, speeches, translations, literary critiques, and children's fiction. Although most famous for her [Earthsea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea) books, she wrote dozens of speculative fiction novels and short stories, and she must be counted among the most significant names in the history of the genre.

**R.I.P.**

Comment: Le Guin  influenced me more than perhaps any other sci-fi/fantasy writer I've read.  I've always marveled at her ability to write so concisely, while still creating worlds rich with cultural and philosophical trappings.   The *Earthsea* series remains of my all time favorites to this day (I swear, if I read one more Amazon review calling them "A poor man's Harry Potter"...), particularly *The Tombs of Atuan*.

Comment: So sad. Her mother lived to a very old age. I had hoped she'd stay with us into her 90s or beyond.

Comment: I admit to never really understanding *Earthsea*, but someone handed me a collection that had *The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas*, which clawed into a deep place and never let go.  I'll miss her.

Comment: @Radhil I didn’t realize *The Ones Who Walk Away from Omelas* was LeGuin! I read it in high school; excellent story. *Earthsea* has been on my to-read list for ages, and I never realized I had actually already read something by her.

Comment: Whilst not my favourite fantasy series, I've never read anything that so effectively evokes a fear of darkness and shadows as the Earthsea books (not even Lovecraft), nor a magical system as interesting as the 'true name' concept. Definitely a very notable series and author. I should try some of her other works.

Comment: To me, Le Guin is one of the few who could see beyond the capitalist system and describe a perfectly functioning anarcho-communist society to skeptics. Her works, while being one of the best sci-fi works I ever read, are much more than sci-fi. I will miss her.

Comment: My sole exposure to Le Guin has been the Catwings books, but I found them delightful and shared them with my son.  Perhaps I shall pick up her better known works as well.

Comment: I read about a dozen books by Le Guin over the course of a few years without ever realizing it was the same author. It was only when I was putting together a list of books I'd loved for an assignment that I realized that her name kept popping up, over and over. I think I speak for everyone when I say her loss is a loss for the entire species.